# How do I enable Impersonation in my MVC website?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, windows-authentication, impersonation

I've had Windows Authentication working in the Cassini (Visual Studio) web server for some time now but when I changed to run my site in IIS 7 the site no longer works properly.

I have Anonymous Authentication disabled, Windows Authentication enabled, and ASP.NET Impersonation enabled.  My web.config file includes:

```
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <identity impersonate="true" />
```

**The problem is that whenever I try to access the site I am prompted to provide a username and password.**

My expectation is that my browser will send my credentials to IIS (via some kind of auth token) and IIS will impersonate my user on all page requests.

**Why am I being prompted to login?**  What must I do to avoid this prompt and have ASP.NET use my impersonated username?

**UPDATE:** 
I added my site to the "Intranet zone" in IE and using IE I no longer get prompted for username and password.  There was a setting in IE to Autologin for intranet sites.

However, I don't understand why this was not a problem using the Cassini web server in VS?  Any ideas?

Comment: Intranet Zone is actually not an IE-exclusive feature... Chrome taps into this Windows Control Panel setting so when I add localhost to it all is well.  I'm a bit frightened by this but perhaps this is how it is supposed to work?  Oddly enough, Firefox does not seem to tap into the Windows Internet Properties.

Comment: If I recall it right, Firefox has an options to behave like that but it's turned off by default.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this against IIS Express?

This is just a stab, but Visual Studio runs both Cassini and IE from the same user account, so perhaps your identity impersonate was passing through from Visual Studio. IIS 7 user account is established by the app pool, which could be a different user than was running VS / Cassini. I believe IIS Express runs as your user account, so identity impersonate might work against it without prompting or changing intranet zone settings.

If that works, you can configure the IIS 7 app pool to run as your user account, and the prompts might go away.

Again, this is just a stab.